# Approach to peek at next item (not just one char) in whitespace separated file using fstream

Tags: c++

While trying to implement a program to process a series of white-space separated values from a file, I came across the problem that I can not peek at the output that the >> operator returns while leaving it in the ifstream to be the next thing returned.

The peek operator exists, but it only reads one character and my values are numbers of uncertain number of digits. Hence, it is not a solution to my particular problem. The >> operator however is more flexible, allowing for retrieval of the next "item", but does not give any peek functionality that leaves the file stream unchanged.

I did find another way to solve my particular problem, but I would appreciate if someone could tell me if there is a way to simulate peeking at the fstream contents. A bidirectional stream seems difficult to use and my impression was that it might require resetting a buffer, which I though might be time intensive (so I rejected that approach as I knew that was not something I knew how to easily implement and I did not know how efficient that is for processing long data sets (> 20,000 white-space separated entries).

This question relates to finding consecutive duplicates in a long stream of file contents, so that I can adjust my processing of entries accordingly. In my case, the question involves numbers, but it could just as easily apply to a white-space seperated list of words.

For example, file1 may contain 23 45 67 67 823 ...

In other words, before I process the first 67, I want to know how many I have in a row, so I can adjust accordingly. In my case, numbers are in ascending order.
The >> operator can retrieve the next value but then it is no longer in the input file stream (ifstream) reading from that file.

I have a solution, but want to expand my knowledge, and may decide if the solution is elegant enough to revise mine. Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: no there isn't. Not without writing a whole bunch of code that, essentially, implements this functionality from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to process your data would be to load them in memory first, and then perform all the processing. According to your examples, 20.000 numbers of 2-5 digits does not seem like a memory killer, and I would go for this.

If you cannot afford memory consumption, you can resort to managing the file offsets by yourself. If you want to read the files in an arbitrary fashion (fast-forward + normal reading), you should resort to manipulating the file offsets through seek*() functions.

Basically you save the current file offset, you perform all the reads you need, you restore the offset.

If you are absolutely requiring the best algorithm (performance) to find your next "\n" or next-number you might want to "minimize your maximum regret" while performing your seeks. Take a look at : http://datagenetics.com/blog/july22012/index.html